# Rails how to populate stars according to score?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Currently its just populating empty starts:

[image]

```
def icon name
    content_tag(:span, nil, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-#{name}")
end

def display_stars score
    # here i need to somehow use icon('star')
    (1..5).map { |i| icon('star-empty') }.join.html_safe
end
```

But let's say my score now 3, and it should display following:

[image]

Comment: Maybe check i<=score each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def display_stars(score)
  (1..5).map do |i| 
    icon(i <= score ? 'star' : 'star-empty')   
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def display_stars score
  full = (1..score).map { |i| icon('star') }
  empty = (score..4).map { |i| icon('star-empty') }
  (full+empty).join.html_safe
end
```

***PS:*** I'm assuming that `stars` range from 0 to 5